# Copying binary files using fread and fwrite

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I have a problem when copying binary files using `fread` and `fwrite`:
the loop runs only two times (40 bytes), but the file length is 160 bytes:

```
#include <string.h>
#define PER_READ 30
int main(void)
{

    char buffer[500] = { 0 };
    FILE* CSV = fopen( "CSV.csv", "rb" );
    FILE* csvDest = fopen( "CSVDest.csv", "wb" );
    unsigned int finished = 0;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    do
    {
        finished = fread( buffer, sizeof( char*), PER_READ, CSV );//Read all from CSV to a string name buffer
        finished += PER_READ * counter;
        counter++;
    } while (finished == PER_READ * counter);
    fwrite( buffer, sizeof( char* ), finished, csvDest );// write all to a the file CSVDest

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return (0);
};
```

Comment: Problem?  What problem, (apart from code formatting)?

Comment: I fixed your code block and removed the spurious backtick at the end.

Comment: Why do you `fwrite(..., sizeof(char*), ...)` of all things?

Comment: @EOF 'cos that's what OP read... :)

Comment: ^^ what EOF says - can you not read and write bytes like normal people?  :)

Comment: DON'T YELL at us! Our eyes are not deaf! (or get your caps-lock repaired)

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation could be a simple loop like this, which repeats until there were no bytes read. Note that `sizeof(char*)` is wrong - the size of a pointer, and that `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                              // include proper header

#define BUFFSIZE    512                                         // power of 2 is kind to system

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    size_t bytes;
    FILE *fin, *fou;
    fin = fopen("CSV.csv", "rb");
    fou = fopen("CSVDest.csv", "wb");
    if(fin == NULL || fou == NULL)
        return 1;                                               // or other action
    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, fin)) != 0) {
        if(fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, fou) != bytes) {
            return 1;                                           // or other action
        }
    }
    fclose(fou);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can i use unsigned int instead of size_t?

Comment: Please ignore my last question.
Ur code worked perfectly, but can U please help me figure out my mistakes in My code?

Comment: The most obvious mistake is to use `sizeof(char*)` when you meant `sizeof(char)`. Another *might* be that the file size may not be a multiple of 30 bytes. Next, you try to read the whole file into a buffer before writing any of it. But rather than struggle with your convoluted attempt, this shows how to keep it simple. Note the `size_t` is the type returned by `fread` and is the required type for two of the arguments for `fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define PER_READ 30
int main( void )
{
    char buffer[500] = { 0 };
    FILE* CSV = fopen( "CSV.csv", "rb" );
    FILE* csvDest = fopen( "CSVDest.csv", "wb" );
    unsigned int finished = 0;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    unsigned int numBlocksRead = 0;
    do
    {
        numBlocksRead = fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), PER_READ, CSV );
        finished += numBlocksRead*sizeof( char );
        counter++;
        fwrite( buffer, sizeof( char ), numBlocksRead, csvDest );

    } while (finished == PER_READ * counter);

    fclose( CSV );
    fclose( csvDest );
    system( "PAUSE" );
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Its 160bytes, Ur code works but it missing the last Line of the CSV file

Comment: Ur code did not compile so i tried to fix it, IT still dont work.
Here is ur updated code(that i tried to fix):
i will edit ur comment

Comment: @OriVAgmon, fixed the bug dude..  fwrite( buffer, sizeof( char ), numBlocksRead, csvDest );  --> i was writing numBlocksRead*PER_READ which was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
finished = fread( buffer, sizeof(char), PER_READ, CSV );
finished += PER_READ * counter;
```

and then you compare:

`while (finished == PER_READ * counter);`

how do expect this to turn out?